# text showing a line above CSS randomly

Tags: html, css

The texts inside buttons class keep showing a line above. 
How can I remove that ?
An example could be the add to cart button or wish-list on the main page http://barajon.com/store/product.php?productid=17533&cat=274&page=1.

Comment: please provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example of the problem](http://sscce.org/) and not a link to your site

Comment: the issue is that, I keep getting a line over text in buttons. an example is add to cart button on the link I just provided. you see how add to cart has a over-line but nothing in the CSS ,to my knowledge, should produce that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are applying that button background image to the `span`s containing the text inside the button (as well as the button itself), via this set of rules:

```
button, button span {
    font-family: Glove;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: url(../../skin/busy-kitchen/css/../images/add2cart.png) no-repeat;
    width: 248px;
    height: 31px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    color: white;
}
```

Remove the `background` rule from this selector to remove the background image from the `span`s, and it should look normal. How that affects the rest of your site, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

if you look closely, you will see that it is in fact a box defining your button class. you need to use `border : none` on your button. as well, the color is not exatly matched inside and outside the button.

Comment: did not work! thanks for the help though

Comment: it did not work, but was I right with my button class? If yes, maibe try border : 0px instead.